# Where should I put the ack configuration file on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, ack

I'm using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com) (the grep replacement) on Windows XP under [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com). Where should the *.ackrc* config file be placed, since *~/.ackrc* is not reasonable on Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For windows (MSWin32, anyway), ack looks in the following places and uses the first file found:

```
$ENV{ACKRC}
$ENV{HOME}/.ackrc
$ENV{HOME}/_ackrc
$ENV{USERPROFILE}/.ackrc
$ENV{USERPROFILE}/_ackrc
```

All but the first are subject to glob-expansion, so watch out for meta-characters in your environment variables.

When not on windows, HOME and USERPROFILE are replaced by ~ and HOME, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

ack looks for either `.ackrc` or `_ackrc` under `%HOME%` or `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 5):

The [ack docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack/ack#THE_.ackrc_FILE) answer your question. Always check the docs. :)